# Fixed navbar at the bottom and justify-content: space-between

Tags: css, position, nav, fixed

i'm trying to make a **nav bar** at the end of a **div**, but the problem i have is that when i put *position: fixed* at it's parent, the *justify.content: space-between* disappear.

This is the code I have:

```
     <main>
        <div>
           <div class="row">
             <div class="logo col-3">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg">
             </div>
            
             <div class="video-container">
                <img src="img/Foto1.jpg">
             </div>
        </div>
        

        <div class="text">
            <p> Some text here </p>
        </div>
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Ask</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Work in progress</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Idea</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
       
       </div>
    </main>
    <style>
      nav{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
      }


      nav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

      nav ul li{
        list-style: none;
      }

      nav ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }
    <style>
```

I would like to have a nav bar fixed and justified.